# Java Optionals: Return value or do something and continue the loop

Tags: java, option-type

In a loop I have code similar to this

```
    for (Id id : ids) {
        Item item = itemRepo.findbyId(id);

        if(item == null) {
            Log.error("No item by id");
            continue;
        }

        // bla bla bla
    }
```

What is the best way to rewrite this using Optionals ?

I tried to rewrite and wanted to use ifPresentOrElse to make code shorter but for the method [ifPresentOrElse()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-optional) is written

> When we have an Optional instance, often we want to execute a specific action on the underlying value of it. On the other hand, if the Optional is empty we want to log it or track that fact by incrementing some metric.

Hence, I just can not return value if it is there.
Any suggestions?.

Thank you.

**UPDATE: I'm sorry, forgot to mention that I need solution with optional as repository function getById has changed and it returns Optional as result.**

Comment: To me what you currently have sounds good.

Comment: What about just [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)?

Comment: Guys, I forgot something to mention in a question, updated already.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think an `Optional` is needed here, a simple `else` works

```
for (Id id : ids) {
    Item item = itemRepo.findbyId(id);

    if(item == null) {
        Log.error("No item by id");
    } else {
        // bla bla bla
    }
}
```

Comment: Was my bad, forgot to mention change of repository function, already updated. Tnx for comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of Optional, either. But just in case you want to use it, this might work:

```java
List<Id> ids = new ArrayList<Id>();
for (Id id : ids) {
    Optional.ofNullable(itemRepo.findbyId(id))
        .ifPresentOrElse(i -> process(i),
            () -> Log.error("No item by id"));
}
```

In my opinion, Optionals should be used togther with streams. The for-loop is an excellent candidate for a stream.

```java
ids.stream()
    .map(itemRepo::findbyId)
    .map(Optional::ofNullable)
    .forEach(o -> o.ifPresentOrElse(i -> process(i), 
            () -> Log.error("No item by id")));
```

Comment: Optionals are best suited as return values, so it would be best if `findById()` returned an Optional (which would force the programmer calling it to consider what happens if the item was not found). If `findById` can't be changed, then I wouldn't bother wrapping its return value in a Optional.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou you are completely right. I forgot to mention in a question that repository function has changed and now it returns Optional value. That's the reason why I need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Id id : ids) {
    Optional<Item> item = Optional.ofNullable(itemRepo.findbyId(id));

    item.ifPresentOrElse(()->System.out.println(item.get()), this::logNoItem());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good use case for using Optional is to write neat code by avoiding unnecessary null checks.
So here in your code there is one place where Optional can be used -

```
for (Id id : ids) {
    Item item = itemRepo.findbyId(id);

    Item item_notNull = Optional.ofNullable(item).orElse(<deafult instance of Item>);
    // now do anything with item_notNull, it'll never be null
    // bla bla bla
}
```

The limitation of the above code is you are not getting the notification if Item is null. If you want that you can use the below code

```
for (Id id : ids) {
    Optional<Item> item = Optional.ofNullable(Repo.findbyId(id));


    if (item.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("No item by id");
            continue;
        }else{
            //do something
        }


    // bla bla bla
}
```

Comment: If Repo.findbyId(id) is returing optional then it's even more nice, now you don;t have to make it optional manually.